# Alfresco synced ldap users not showing up in Admin Tools -> Users

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-ldap

I recently enabled ldap synchronization in my Alfresco Community Edition instance (running 5.1).

I checked the logs and it appears that the sync is working fine. For my test, I setup an instance running OpenLDAP.

```
2016-10-20 20:22:39,925  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=6 User Creation and Association: Commencing batch of 0 entries
 2016-10-20 20:22:39,925  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Synchronization,Category=directory,id1=ldap1,id2=6 User Creation and Association: Completed batch of 0 entries
 2016-10-20 20:22:39,960  INFO  [security.sync.ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer] [localhost-startStop-1] Finished synchronizing users and groups with user registry 'ldap1'
```

It is showing zero above because an earlier run synced successfully. I was also able to verify this by checking the postgres database

```
COPY alf_authority (id, version, authority, crc) FROM stdin;
12      0       testuser1  1280826318
13      0       testuser2  2382010757
```

testuser1 and testuser2 are what I added on LDAP.

However, when I check the users added under admin tools (`http://localhost:8080/share/page/console/admin-console/users` on my instance) I don't see these users

I've looked at many links and forums and this doesn't seem to be discussed. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Is your search working okay?

Comment: Nope. Still in the blind.

Comment: Is there a user you do see? Can you compare the two nodes and see if there are any differences, for example a missing aspect? Jeff is probably aiming at something SOLR related.

Comment: Ok got it. My situation is that

* Alfresco is syncing with LDAP 
* Users get added to postgres on Alfresco
* They don't show up in the search interface

None of the LDAP users show up there. The users I add as part of alfresco admin ("alfresco users") do show up.

Comment: Can you successfully authenticate as an LDAP user?

Comment: No I cannot. Alfresco seems to treat these users as non existent.

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue for new test user : they were synchronised, could log in alfresco with but not visible in admin tools...
But we could access the modification page of the users by typing the correct url by hand.

The problem came from the filed LDAP LastName on our AD which was empty.

We added infos to the LastName field and voilà ! We can now see them in the Admin Tools...
May be it is your case ?